# How to make Pairs using Stream for two lists

Tags: java, java-stream

I have two lists:

```
List<Flight> flightsToCity = findFlightToCity(airport);
List<Flight> flightsFromCity = findFlightFromCity(airport);
```

Elements of lists are flights. I must connect every flights from list flightsToCity, with every element of second list and this must be pairs. I must do this with stream and result it must be `List<Pair<Flight, Flight>>`
For example:

```
flightsToCity:

London -> Warsow,
Berlin -> Warsow

flightFromCity:

Warsow -> Barcelona,
Warsow -> Zakopane

Result:

London -> Warsow, Warsow -> Barcelona
London -> Warsow, Warsow -> Zakopane
Berlin -> Warsow, Warsow -> Barcelona
Berlin -> Warsow, Warsow -> Zakopane
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-

Comment: *I must do this with stream and result it must be `List<Pair<Flight, Flight>>`*... and its good to start off with your attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the lists have the same size and the elements are in the right order you could use an [IntStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) to solve your problem.

```
        List<Pair<Flight, Flight>> flightsOfAirport = IntStream
            .range(0, flightsFromCity.size())
            .mapToObj(index -> Pair.of(flightsToCity.get(index), flightsFromCity.get(index)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```